# Dismissing keyboard in phonegap application moves header

Tags: ios, header, cordova, keyboard, footer

I'm developing a phonegap application, and some of it's pages have a form in them.
The app has a fixed header and footer, and the contents of the page is scrollable ( sometimes it's larger than the screen ).

When I'm focused on an input field of the form and dismiss it by clicking outside of it, the header of the app moves next to the clicking position and drops its "fix" to the top.

This issue occures only under iOS.

I cannot take screenshots to show the problem, but I have (poorly) illustrated it:

1. The way the page looks normally:
   [image]
2. When I click on a specific text field (it's actually a number text field), the keyboard opens up:
   [image]
   I can scroll the content up and down even when the keyboard is open, until I reach the header or the footer, both visible. This is not a bug, just think it might be relevant.
3. If I click outside of the form (specifically, where the blue point is in the previous picture is), The header drops to that point:
   [image]
   I can scroll the page and the overflow will show above the header. If I re-focus on a field, the header returns to its proper position.
   It should be mentioned as well that if I dismiss the keyboard with the "done" button instead of pressing outside the focused input, there is no distortion at all.

I have tried the following solution:
[Phonegap JQM Fixed Position Header/Footer Moves After Dismissing iOS Keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8992502/phonegap-jqm-fixed-position-header-footer-moves-after-dismissing-ios-keyboard)
It does work eventually, but you can see the movement of the header and the background behind it, so it's not a good solution for me.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: You probably comes across article on how fixed position is not very mobile friendly.  I suggest you relative position the header and make the content scrollable with top margin equal to header size.