# PhoneGap; iOS keyboard causes frame to move upwards after each keystroke

Tags: ios, cordova

I have an app that a couple of clients are using, and we've noticed that during certain cases of using the app that the view moves up when using the keyboard. Which, the view then becomes stuck there, like space is constantly being added to the bottom of the view, making it look like the bottom of the view.

This only appears to happen on iOS (devices are using either version 5, 6, or 7), but not Android. I've tried changing the option KeyboardShrinksView directly in the iOS project (we use appery.io and are building the iOS project by exporting it through Appery).

The last time I looked at the problem as several months ago (we're beta testing a much larger project) and I did see others online saying that they experienced similar issues. So I don't know if others still have this issue, or don't now with the semi-recent release of phoneGap 3.3.

Even if this question has been asked before, I'm hoping that the issue will get back to phoneGap.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i've seen similar issues been solved by adding `height=device-height` to your viewport in your html.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="height=device-height,width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0,user-scalable=no" />
```

if that doesn't work, try forcing a page redraw on input blur, like shown in this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18856929/1656561